# How to print the column statistics for an Oracle SQL table like pandas' `describe` command does for a DataFrame

Tags: sql, oracle, command-line, statistics

How can I print the column statistics for an SQL table like *number of unique values*, *max* and *min value*, etc?

I am interested in statistics the command line tool [csvstat](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvstat.html) or  pandas' [`describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) and `min`/`max`/`mean` methods print out.

Note: I do *not* want to load the data completely in memory, so that pandas can analyse them.

Is there any command line tool which reads the SQL data on the fly to create these statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just a rough estimate, you can access Oracle's data dictionary's statistics, that Oracle maintains automatically, generally daily.  The table  `ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS` has number of distinct values, number of nulls, and minimum and more.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS.html#GUID-40AC6263-089D-4471-B2E2-EBCA15BC4C65) says that minimum and maximum values for a particular column are held in the columns `LOW_VALUE` and `HIGH_VALUE` in the `ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS` table but those columns are a data type `RAW(1000)` so the data in those columns may need to be decoded.

If you need to occasionally get better estimates, you can invoke the [dbms_stats.gather_table_stats](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_STATS.html#GUID-CA6A56B9-0540-45E9-B1D7-D78769B7714C) procedure before querying the `ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS` table.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. That's more or less what I was looking for. Shame that `LOW_VALUE` and `HIGH_VALUE` are not plainly interpretable. I still see the need for a program which does the `gather_table_stats` refresh, queries the table, decodes the values and then pretty prints the stuff. Well, one day...

Comment: Yeah, I've glanced at some of Oracle's data dictionary views that decode a `RAW` column, and it is usually a bunch of nested `BITAND(expr1, expr2)` functions.  And likely to change at major Oracle software versions.